# Unity, OnMouseOver blocked by another gameobject with a collider in front of it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two gameobjects, both with 2D colliders.

One of them can be behind the other, and because of this its OnMouseOver can be blocked from firing as the GameObject in front blocks it from triggering.

What is a way around this? I really like the ease of using OnMouseOver, and would rather not use raycastAll.

Comment: Internally I believe OnMouseOver uses a pain raycast, so you're probably stuck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465363/restricting-onmousedown-event-on-specific-collides

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 possibilities:

1. Use RayCast.All() but you said, that you want to avoid that.
2. Set the "blocking" GameObject to the [Layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) "[IgnoreRayCast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreRaycastLayer.html)"
3. [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465363/restricting-onmousedown-event-on-specific-collides/42468331#42468331) answer has a third possibility.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to use raycast all here.